# Django `TimeField` and timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, timefield

Django documents says "Timezone withoud date no make sence" but I think it does. For example: DB store time of day start. User from Chicago saved start time as 05:00 am. System need to generate report for every day and use this start time with date (datetime field). So for summer days it will 10:00 by UTC, but for winter it will 11:00 by UTC.

The question is: how to generate datetime from frimefield and current date? Store timezone in special separate field?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts
[image]

Comment: You'll need to combine that time to a datetime somewhere and add a timezone to it; *then* it makes sense. Since just a time by itself with a timezone makes no sense, the `TimeField` won't store the timezone. So yes, store the timezone name in a separate column.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! You can put it as answer and I will accept this